# How to make everyone can reply this but if answer wrong or true only show for user that replied before

Tags: discord, discord.py

i'm wanna make discord.py quiz which user can see a question but i want to make user can answer by replying this question but if a user answer true/false/timeout, it only send to user that has answered but can visible to everyone

```
@client.command()
async def ask(ctx):
    quiz_data = {
        'question_1': (["1", "One"], "one"),
        'question_2': (["2", "Two"], "two"),
    }
    question = random.choice(list(quiz_data.keys()))
    answers, hint = quiz_data[question]

    await ctx.send("What is the answer to this question?")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(question)

    def check_sender(msg): 
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

    def check_answer(msg):
        return any(answer in msg.content for answer in answers) 

    try:
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_sender, timeout=10)
        if check_answer(msg):
            await ctx.send("good")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send(f"What is the answer to this question? hint: {hint}")
        await ctx.send(question)

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_sender, timeout=None)
        if check_answer(msg):
            await ctx.send("good")
        else: 
            await ctx.send("wrong.")
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 separate check functions? Just combine them into one

Answer (score 0):

I think that it isn't possible to make a message in a server show for only one user (using discord.py), but you can alternatively DM the user by using

```
    await ctx.author.send("<MESSAGE>")
```

This will send them a direct message with whatever message you want